# How to use EL in PrimeFaces oncomplete attribute which is updated during action method

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, el

This is code:

```
 <p:ajax event="eventResized" process="@this calendar"  listener="#{bean.eventResized}" oncomplete="resizeComplete()"/>
```

`eventReized` invoked by `EventResizeBehavior` which extended from `AjaxBehaviorEvent` and it contains some property. Can I check inside `<p:ajax....>` call its value and pass result to `oncomplete="resizeComplete(result)"`

Something like that

```
<p:ajax event="eventResized" process="@this calendar"  listener="#{bean.eventResized}" oncomplete="resizeComplete(#{eventResized.id == 0})"/>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PrimeFaces doesn't support it. Any EL expressions in `oncomplete` attribute are immediately evaluated during render response of that HTML document, not during oncomplete of the associated ajax call. Basically, the JavaScript code generated by `oncomplete` attribute contains the old value as it was during the page load.

Your best bet is using [`RequestContext#addCallbackParam()`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/5.0/org/primefaces/context/RequestContext.html#addCallbackParam(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) to add a property to the PrimeFaces-specific `args` object which is available in `oncomplete` scope.

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().addCallbackParam("result", eventResized.getId() == 0);
```

```
<p:ajax ... oncomplete="resizeComplete(args.result)" />
```

An alternative is to use [`RequestContext#execute()`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/5.0/org/primefaces/context/RequestContext.html#execute(java.lang.String)) instead of `oncomplete` to programmatically instruct PrimeFaces to execute a piece of JavaScript on complete of the ajax request.

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("resizeComplete(" + (eventResized.getId() == 0) + ")");
```

Comment: Thank you BalusC, I suspected that I will need to use mixed solution, but didn't know how to it such simple like your solution.

Comment: You're welcome. I'd like to note that RichFaces supports the construct as you'd intuitively expect, it would indeed have been nice if PrimeFaces did that too.

Comment: If you are using Primefaces version 7+ you can use `PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("...")`, see this thread for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55285566/primefaces-requestcontext-under-7-0