# Primefaces RequestContext under 7.0

Tags: primefaces

My pre-7.0 Primefaces application has this code:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("window.open('myUrl');");
```

I understand that RequestContext is no longer available in 7.0.  What is the equivalent to perform the same action?

Comment: In PF 6.2 all these calls are deprecated with appropriate hint.

Comment: Its all in the migration guide: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/wiki/Migration-Guide

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Beside other changes the `RequestContext` class has been deprecated in version 6.2 and removed in version 7.0 of Primefaces. It is replaced by calling `PrimeFaces.current()`. In your case, the code should be changed to:

```
PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("window.open('myUrl');");
```

Please keep looking into the [migration guide](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/wiki/Migration-Guide) (already linked by @Melloware in comment) when upgrading your Primefaces dependency.

Comment: Maybe add some text as well, e.g. from your comment

Comment: @Kukeltje Why text? Just kidding - planned so too and hoped to find a PF 'migration guide' I can refer to but I could not manage to open the docs on mobile yet. But on the first go I wanted to send a hello to the VLQQ ;D