# Primefaces 7.0 alternatives for old libraries?

Tags: primefaces, libraries

My task is to get our project running with PrimeFaces 7.0. The current version runs on Primefaces 6.2. A lot of our used Libraries are now removed and I'm looking for alternatives.

We use :

```
org.primefaces.component.organigram.OrganigramHelper

org.primefaces.context.RequestContext

org.primefaces.event.CloseEvent, DashboardReorderEvent, FileUploadEvent, ItemSelectEvent, NodeSelectEvent

org.primefaces.event.organigram.OrganigramNodeCollapseEvent, OrganigramNodeDragDropEvent, OrganigramNodeExpandEvent, OrganigramNodeSelectEvent

org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent, TabChangeEvent, ToggleEvent

org.primefaces.model.chart.AxisType, ChartSeries, DateAxis, LegendPlacement, LineChartModel, LineChartSeries, DashboardColumn, DashboardModel, DefaultDashboardColumn, DefaultDashboardModel, DefaultOrganigramNode, DefaultStreamedContent, DefaultTreeNode, OrganigramNode, SelectableDataModel, StreamedContent, TimelineModel, TreeNode, UploadedFile
```

Since I just started using primefaces some weeks ago I would appreciate your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Primefaces RequestContext under 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55285566/primefaces-requestcontext-under-7-0)

Comment: A lot of classes you mentioned are not removed in PF 7.0. What's the problem with them?

Comment: they all say that they don't exist!

Comment: I think you might have a library conflict because all of those classes exist except RequestContext which stated above has a replacement in the Migration Guide.

Comment: ok. I've already tried PrimeFaces.current() but it can't be found as well...